# Is posible to use a font from a local folder outisde Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts

I need lo load a font from Windows Fonts folder or somewhere outside Unity because I need to give my customer the ability to add whatever font he wants and then use it in unity.

Until now I tried loading the font in a byte array and then use it. This is my code (doesn´t work)

```
byte[] fontData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fontPath);

            Font font = new Font();
            Material fontMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("UI/Default"));
            font.material = fontMaterial;
            font.material.mainTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);

            ((Texture2D)font.material.mainTexture).LoadImage(fontData);

            TMP_FontAsset fontAsset = TMPro.TMP_FontAsset.CreateFontAsset(font);
```